# Looking for "Domino combination" algorithm

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation

I'm going to complete my apprenticeship as coder and I got a nice j2me project to work on, but I have to admit that I'm not that good with mathematical algorithms as I'd like to be.

My problem is to create all possible "domino pairs" from a given set of values. 
For example: The possible values go from 0 to 6. Now imagine some domino tokens with those values. The output should then be something like this:

00 
01 
02 
03 
04 
05 
06 
11 
12 
13 
...

Each pair only appears a single time but pairs with two equal values are possible.

I've already searched for this problem, but either I didn't find a solution for this particular problem or I didn't really understand how the algorithms work.

I'd really appreciate any explanations and algorithms. Feel free to post alternative solutions as well. I'd prefer to not just have a solution, but to understand it as well ;)

Comment: This question seems to get asked in one form or another almost every day... this should be the new FizzBuzz problem (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000781.html)

Comment: I don't mean to be cruel, but if you're completing your apprenticeship and you don't know how to write nested loops, perhaps you should reconsider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
for i from 0 to n inclusive
   for j from i to n inclusive
       output i,j
```

The important point is that the second loop doesn't start from zero. This means we don't have to test if a domino has already been used. We know that all dominos produced using this algorithm are unique because of the way the algorithm is constructed.

Comment: Good one, you pipped me by a few minutes, with an essentially identical answer, so I've deleted mine.

Comment: And i always thought, i had to use recursion ;) 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please give the OP time to at least show their attempt first. Otherwise you're cheating them the opportunity to learn to create their own code and not motivating them to improve their question up to site standards.